# c# Webclient.UploadData works on local, but fails on server

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ftp, upload, webclient

I am trying to deploy a website but am having an error with one of my forms that has an image upload.

Firstly i am using NetworkSolutions for the hosting, and one of the forms has an file upload input for images. When I run the application locally and upload the image to the FTP, everything works correctly, however when i deploy to the server, the connection appears to timeout (since it hangs for a few moments), than i get the message **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**. One thing i should note is SSL is not setup on this server, however i am using an unsecure port.

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Submit(RegistrationViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", viewModel);
        }
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {

            string path = String.Empty;
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName); // Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                try
                {
                    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                    {
                        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("***", "***");

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[file.ContentLength];
                        file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        file.InputStream.Close();


                        path = "ftp://***.***.com:21/pics/" + fileName;
                        client.UploadData(path, buffer);

                    }
                }
                catch (WebException ex)
                {
                    string status = ((FtpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusDescription;

                }
            }

            Context.Registrations.Add(new Registration
            {
                FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
                LastName = viewModel.LastName,
                Email = viewModel.Email,
                PhoneNumber = viewModel.PhoneNumber,
                Age = viewModel.Age,
                ImagePath = path,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
            });

            await Context.SaveChangesAsync();

            ConfirmationViewModel confirmViewModel = new ConfirmationViewModel
            {
                FirstName = viewModel.FirstName,
                LastName = viewModel.LastName,
                Email = viewModel.Email,
                PhoneNumber = viewModel.PhoneNumber
            };

            return RedirectToAction("Confirm", "Register", confirmViewModel);
        }
}
```

I expect that the image should save to the path as it does locally, however on the server i cannot get pass this timeout/null exception. The exception in the stack trace is when the method UploadData hits, in the register controller line 89 (im showing the Submit function in the register controller). Since this issue is happening on the server, getting feedback on the error has been fairly limiting. Removing the try/catch i get internal server error, with the try catch, i get Null reference exception.

One thing i tried was removing the lines assuming something was null here, but same result:

```
file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
file.InputStream.Close();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you will have to put more details about the exception and the line number where the code is breaking...!

Comment: Updated the original post. "The exception in the stack trace is when the method UploadData hits, in the register controller line 89 (im showing the Submit function in the register controller)"

Comment: I have continued testing. I tried using the main FTP account with full admin rights and the same issue occurred. I tried writing to a directory where the website resides rather than going through FTP and there was an access denied error.  So it seems i am limited to going through the FTP. This issue has been going on for quite some time, and each time i try to test on the server, its a minimum 10 minute each time to publish.

Answer (score 0):

I have tracked down the Object reference not set to an instance of an object exception comes from the catch statement. The exception does not seem to be a WebException, or at least the response i was casting was not an FtpWebResponse. (very difficult to debug since i have to deploy each time), however i am still timing out for some unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully saved the image to the server from the server! The issue came down to the request being made specifically from the web server domain to the ftp domain.

Hidden in NetworkSolution options was folder privileges (Security/Password Protection for anyone looking), after allowing write access on the directory i needed, i switched my method to use the HttpPostedFileBase to save the file directly to the server, and success! I wish I was able to find that option from the start and save hours of headache.